# How to "touch" (update the date of) files in a selection in Finder?

Tags: applescript, finder

One thing I do a lot is prepare images for posting to social media, and I sometimes want to "touch" some images (change the modification date to now) via Applescript. The script below works fine if I want to drag files to an Applescript app, but what I really want is a script that "touches anything currently selected in the finder" without being run in an "on open" loop. (This is so I can run it any time from Keyboard Maestro, the best tool for Mac users since Multifinder.)

Every attempt to do a simple set selection, loop through selection, etc. causes errors for some reason, because the finder can't get the info of a file in a selection, or something. Can anyone possibly suggestion something?

The original script

```
on open these_items
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_items
        set this_item to (item i of these_items)
        set the item_info to info for this_item
        if folder of the item_info is true then
            process_folder(this_item)
        else
            process_item(this_item)
        end if
    end repeat
end open

-- this sub-routine processes folders 
on process_folder(this_folder)
    do shell script "touch \"" & POSIX path of this_folder & "\""
    set these_items to list folder this_folder without invisibles
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_items
        set this_item to alias ((this_folder as text) & ¬
            (item i of these_items))
        set the item_info to info for this_item
        if folder of the item_info is true then
            process_folder(this_item)
        else
            process_item(this_item)
        end if
    end repeat
end process_folder

-- this sub-routine processes files 
on process_item(this_item)
    do shell script "touch \"" & POSIX path of this_item & "\""
end process_item
-- Rob
```

Comment: This is not working for me:

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple routine that touched all items selected in the Finder.

```
on touchMe()
    tell application "Finder"
        set myList to the selection
        repeat with myFile in myList
            set myTempItem to myFile as alias
            set myPosixItem to POSIX path of myTempItem
            set myShell to "touch \"" & myTempItem & "\""
            set result to (do shell script myShell with administrator privileges)
            return result
        end repeat
    end tell
end touchMe
```

**Edit:** added admin privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually get an error (Finder got an error: touch: Mac HD:Users:pp:Desktop:Untitled-1.jpg: Permission denied) when I run this as a normal script with the On touchMe() removed (so make it just run without needing to be called). Is there any way around this? It's like Finder is touchy about permissions when working with the files directly but is okay if they're dragged onto a script app.

Comment: What version of Mac OS X do you use? If I make the script return an error on purpose, I get slashes and no colons in the file path. That's a strange difference. You can run the same script with admin privileges. I'll change the script and you can try again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. I will post the script that's giving me problems after this.

Comment: This gives an error: tell app "Finder"
set mySelection to selection
repeat with anItem in mySelection
set itemName to anItem's name
tell me
touchMe(anItem) -- can only use with images
end tell
end repeat
end tell

on touchMe()
tell app "Finder"
set myList to the selection
repeat with myFile in myList
set myTempItem to myFile as alias
set myPosixItem to POSIX path of myTempItem
set myShell to "touch \"" & myTempItem & "\""
set the clipboard to myShell
set result to (do shell script myShell with administrator privileges)
return result
end repeat
end tell
end touchMe

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to post a proper large formatted script response, only these comments. Basically the "with admin privilleges" seems to require a password, and then the script doesn't perform the same function anyway.

Comment: Since there's an Applescript script that works fine when I drop a JPG on the app icon, is there no way to tell the Applescript app to "open" (execute using) a certain file? This is really stumping me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help. I got it to work using a script like this:

```
 tell application "Finder"
    set mySelection to selection
    set mySelection2 to selection as text
    tell me
        set mySelection2 to replace_chars(mySelection2, "Mac HD", "")
        set mySelection2 to replace_chars(mySelection2, ":", "/")
        set mySelection2 to replace_chars(mySelection2, " ", "\\ ")
    end tell
    do shell script "touch " & mySelection2 user name "userid" password "password" with administrator privileges

 end tell

 on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_text
 end replace_chars
```